# how do you add the state "DC" to the states list in the 'us' package in python

Tags: python-3.x, import

```
import us

for st in us.state.STATES:
    print(st)
```

The code above prints the states of the US but it does not include Washington DC. Any idea how I can do that?

According to [this link](https://github.com/unitedstates/python-us), I need to set the environment variable `DC_STATEHOOD = 1`. Any idea how to do that (and get DC in the states)? Thanks.

Comment: Washingon, DC is not yet a state. A bill has been introduced to make it one, but it has not passed yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree DC is not a state yet, however, it is still considered a state in practice.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of us states, it seems the environment variable feature was released with version 3.0.0 (https://github.com/unitedstates/python-us#changelog). However, the latest version of us package available for download seems to be 2.0.2 (https://pypi.org/project/us/2.0.1/). Maybe that's why setting DC_STATEHOOD to 1 doesn't seem to work for `us.STATES`.